# Need to block user role from accessing bbPress all together

Tags: user-roles, user-access, bbpress, private

I've been looking at some options and I haven't seen a full solution to what I need. I need to block certain `user_roles` from accessing bbPress all together and from seeing the link to the page.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this plugin](http://shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/). I've used it and it's quite versatile regarding user roles and user capabilities.

You can also add conditional statements in your php files, like this:

```
if (!current_user_can('some_capability_you_added')) {
   echo "You don't have permission for it!";
   return;
}
```

You can output that sentence or nothing at all.